# Shortcuts for Inserting objects in PowerPoint for Mac

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

The screenshot shows the common items to be inserted into a PowerPoint Presentation. Being on a Mac, of course we are handicapped on not having mnemonics support to perform the action by the keyboard.  Or are there some shortcuts to do these?

[image]

The point here is that needing to hunt for the menu item with the mouse and then click on the item is way slow compared to keyboarding.

**Update**: An answer was provided with a link to the shortcuts provided by MS online help. I should have noted that link had already been pored over and does not mention any shortcuts for "Insert" items.

Comment: Have you looking at either [OS X El Capitan: Create keyboard shortcuts for apps](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21534) or [OS X Yosemite: Create keyboard shortcuts for apps](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18418) and tried creating a application shortcut for the "Text Box" menu command?.

Comment: @user3439894  While it is possible to create custom shortcuts that needs to be then done on every machine I use. I was looking for a built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are keyboard shortcuts for *almost* every menu command.  Here's a link for [Microsoft's Office for Mac keyboard shortcuts site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-PowerPoint-2016-for-Mac-f25f92b3-b0a8-4c60-aec8-954b72aa81ad).  I normally frown on just posting a link but because there's so many shortcuts available it doesn't make sense to copy/paste them all here.

Also, if you don't find the shortcut you're looking for, you can always create your own.

Comment: Maybe I should have noted in the OP that I had already pored through that list.  None of the "Insert" commands are provided.

Comment: Did you create your own shortcut with one of those 'insert' commands that you want?  Maybe that will help.  It looks like Microsoft doesn't want to support keyboard shortcuts for many of those menu commands.

Comment: that is of course an option for any app but a heavyweight one..   I guess there simply aren't shortcuts already available.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no keyboard shortcut, but you can add the Insert Picture command to the Quick Access Toolbar (via Powerpoint/Preferences/Ribbon & Toolbar).  This greatly simplifies the process.

Comment: thanks to MIchael Mitchell I added Insert Picture and Insert Textbox in the toolbar, although the path was different for me: Powerpoint->View->Customize Toolbars and Menus-> Insert-> Picture and dragged the icon to my toolbar . thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you (and me) are looking for are the "goto" or "alt" shortcuts which allow you to access the ribbons in Windows. For example, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for the insert ribbon followed by the <kbd>X</kbd>for the text box.

[How do I navigate the ribbon in Office for Mac 2016 with the keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237327/how-do-i-navigate-the-ribbon-in-office-for-mac-2016-with-the-keyboard)

The quick answer is, it is not implemented, but the above question answers suggests a few work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

**For Inserting a Text Box**

1. **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**
2. click the '+'
3. **Menu Title** = [text box]
4. **Keyboard Shortcut** = [type your prefered shortcut]
5. click **Add**